# Capacity and BER as performance of transmission system

Tags: digital-communications

We study the performance of the transmission system by channel capacity or BER/SER. If the system performance is studied as BER/SER, does it make sense to study a channel capacity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Channel Capacity and Bit/Symbol Error rate are two different key performance indicators (**KPI**) of a system.

**BER/SER**, as it's obvious from its name, is  the number of Bit/Symbol errors divided by the total number of transferred Bits/Symbols. and you can use channel coding to improve it so it's not a fixed KPI.
while **Channel Capacity** is maximum rate that the system can achieve and it's a fixed KPI.

so it make sense to study the channel capacity of your system. by studying channel capacity you find maximum rate that can be achieved and by improving BER/SER you can improve rate of system to get close to channel capacity.

Comment: "number of errors per Bit/Symbol", typo? SER (or BER) is symbol (or bit) error rate, e.g. 1 error per 10000 symbols (or  bits(.

Comment: @P2000 I changed it. is it better now?